# How to count the number of trues in a table in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a table like this

| StudID | Date | I | II | III | IV | V | VI | VII | VIII |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2-10-11 | T | T | F | F | F | F | F | T |
| 101 | 2-10-11 | T | T | T | F | F | F | F | T |
| 100 | 3-10-11 | T | F | F | F | F | F | F | T |
| 100 | 4-10-11 | T | F | F | F | F | F | F | T |

Now i need to get the number of T's i.e, Trues in the table for a particular student in a particular month
StudID is a varchar field
Date is a datetime field
and all the other datatype with bit

any ideas?

Comment: First, normalize your table so that you have four columns: StudID, Date, ItemName, and Value. ItemName will replace your I, II, III, and so on columns. Value will hold either T/F.

Comment: You should consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data

Comment: @Yuch unfortunately i must not normalize it...  thanx interest

Answer (score 7):

As the comments suggest, you should normalize your data.

However if you are unable to do that, you simply need to count the number of trues in each row.

```
context.Studs.Sum(s => (s.I ? 1 : 0) + (s.II ? 1 : 0) + ... + (s.VIII ? 1 : 0));
```

edit: To restrict the sum based on StudID and the month, you would use a `Where` operator

```
var id = "100";
var month = 10;

var set = context.Studs.Where(s => s.StudID == id;
set = set.Where(s => s.Date.Month == month);

return set.Sum(s => (s.I ? 1 : 0) + (s.II ? 1 : 0) + ... + (s.VIII ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: Consider he wants the result for a particular student in a particular month

Comment: @Krik it was nice i got it thanx

Answer (score 2):

```
var numberOfTrues = context.Students.
Where(x => x.StudID == 123 && x.Date.Month == studentMonth).
Sum(x => x.I.ToInt() + x.II.ToInt() + ... + x.VIII.ToInt());


// Add extension method    
public static int ToInt(this bool value)
{
   return value ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var student = context.Students.Where(s => s.StudID == id && s.Date.Month == month).Single();

var trues = from results in student.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    let val = (bool)f.GetValue(student, null)
    where val
    select val;
// You can now check trues.Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the T and F actually are characters and not bit/booleans then you could try

```
context.Studs.Sum(s => (s.I+s.II+s.III+s.IV).Count(c => c=='T') );
```

but I wonder what the generated SQL will look like. Problably not something like

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(REPLACE(I+II+III+IV, 'F', '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a function called something like bool CheckBit(StudID, Date, num) where you pass in the StudID, Date, and a number from 1 to 8.  Put the function call in a loop and pass in 1 - 8 and keep a count of how many times you return true